# javascript: How to trigger an if statement when a variable equals a number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Basically what I have is an array with these numbers:
`var songTimer = [0,12,49]`. What I want to happen is that every time `audio.currentTime`(a built in javascript variable for audio) reaches any of the numbers in songTimer's array, it will trigger an if statement (say, post a message in the console). I haven't written any code for this yet, so yeah.

Comment: like check every second the value in `audio.currentTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var songTimer = [0,12,49];
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
  if (songTimer.includes(audio.currentTime)) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```js
var songTimer = [0,12,49];

if (songTimer.includes(audio.currentTime)) {
  // do something
}
```